# Is there any way to fetch code from a server at runtime and execute it?

Tags: flutter, dart, client, runtime, execute

The question mainly focuses on the Dart language (for Flutter) but general solutions are of course welcomed too.
So, is there any way to fetch and execute code?

Answer (score 2):

For now I would say No! There is no way that you can evaluate a code from another source in Dart in AOT (ahead-of-time) compilation mode which is used by Flutter for generating releases. But you can use Dart's `isolate` in JIT (just-in-time) mode to evaluate a string object containing Dart code. You can read more about it in [This](https://iiro.dev/2019/08/15/how-to-eval-in-dart/) link.

Comment: Thank you very much!